# What is easy way send typing text to server in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I know case how do this in Jquery by cheking event `keypress`, but how do it in Angular JS? I want to send to server AJAX request for searching data via ElasticSearch. Need I use timeout in typing text event?

Is enought example from tutorial? This example shows value in template, but I need get in controller

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ngChange` directive:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

```
<input type="text" ng-change="nameChanged()" ng-model="name"></input>
```

Comment: It will be  very load server if send request after each passed symbol? Thanks

Comment: @Sahe your original question didn't suggest you were having issues with server load, only that you wanted to know how to reproduce what you were already doing in JQuery....